# How to run a trigger when updating a different object in SFDC?

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I've created a new trigger(before insert, before update) for a custom object which is going to take the information from a Standard Object (Opportunity) this is the problem that i'm facing..

I'm pulling information from the the Opportunity object (lookup field to User) to the new record in the custom object to trigger email alerts when this custom record is created... (i can't use formulas here) with this method everything is going to work when the custom record is created after that all the information is populated on the Opportunity.. the Problem is that sometimes the fields that i'm getting from the Opportunity are not populated before the custom record is created... how can i run the trigger for the custom object when updating the Opportunity record ?? i'm fairly new to APEX so i will like to get some input on how to get this implemented.. ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us more about what your algorithm is supposed to do?

As long as I can give you one piece of advice on the use of triggers: if the trigger has to perform actions on the object to which it is assigned, then use these events - before insert, before update. But if the trigger has to perform actions on other objects, then use events - after insert, after update, after delete.

**More about triggers:**

- [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf)
- [Apex Triggers the    Definitive Guide](http://macscloud.com/salesforce-apex-triggers-the-definitive-guide/)

Comment: Hi dobrobot.. basically what i want to do is based on the update of the Opportunity object run the trigger for another object (which has a lookup relationship to opportunity).. is this even possible ?? based on your comment this will be a modification on the Opportunity trigger (after update) how can i run the trigger for the other object ??? any ideas ?? please advise ! Thanks !

Comment: If you want to change some object(s) when Opportunity object is updated, you can use next way: you can select this object in trigger for opportunity object, after that you can update fields which you wish, and save this object to database. If you need, I can write little example for this situation